# Display HTML in RSS

Tags: html, wordpress, rss

Is there any way on earth that I could pump some HTML through an RSS feed? I realize I'm bending the laws of science and all, but I'm under some tight circumstances. I have Wordpress set up so I'm posting a bit of HTML/Inline CSS in one end, and on another site, another web team is going to parse the RSS.

Is there any possible way to do this? Am I crazy? If not, is there another solution?

Comment: Related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113024/whats-the-best-way-to-pass-html-embed-code-via-rss-feed-to-a-rss-parser-in-php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674881/perils-of-relying-on-embedded-html-in-rss

Answer (score 5):

HTML embedded in RSS should be entity encoded.  As far as RSS is concerned, it's just text.  The client application needs to know it contains HTML and render it properly.

http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/rss-public/message/24?threaded=1

Answer (score 4):

Use [CDATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) in your XML

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's possible from this link: http://www.intertwingly.net/blog/1299.html. Sounds like glibberish to me, but they seem to succeed in it. Something about . I don't get it.

**Update**:
The [W3C](http://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/rss2.html) says:

> An item may also be complete in
>   itself, if so, the description
>   contains the text (entity-encoded HTML
>   is allowed),

And this works for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rss version="2.0">
   <channel>
      <title>Liftoff News</title>
      <link>http://liftoff.msfc.nasa.gov/</link>
      <description>Liftoff to Space Exploration.</description>
      <language>en-us</language>
      <pubDate>Tue, 10 Jun 2003 04:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
      <lastBuildDate>Tue, 10 Jun 2003 09:41:01 GMT</lastBuildDate>
      <docs>http://blogs.law.harvard.edu/tech/rss</docs>
      <generator>Weblog Editor 2.0</generator>
      <managingEditor>editor@example.com</managingEditor>
      <webMaster>webmaster@example.com</webMaster>
      <item>
         <description>Sky watchers in <strong><big>Europe</big></strong>, Asia, and parts of Alaska and Canada will experience a &lt;a href="http://science.nasa.gov/headlines/y2003/30may_solareclipse.htm"&gt;partial eclipse of the Sun&lt;/a&gt; on Saturday, May 31st.</description>
         <pubDate>Fri, 30 May 2003 11:06:42 GMT</pubDate>
         <guid>http://liftoff.msfc.nasa.gov/2003/05/30.html#item572</guid>
      </item>
   </channel>
</rss>
```

Note the strong and big elements in the description. It's displayed properly in Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Encode the html and you won't have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

You should not need HTML if you use XSL to format the page.

Answer (score 0):

there is http://feedoor.com to manage your feed and where you can style your feed and add custom CSS

Answer (score -2):

USE THIS

$fulltext= htmlspecialchars("\n".$row['Description']);

< description > this is &lt ;b &gt ;bold &lt ;/b&gt ;< /description >

In RSS:

< description > $fulltext < /description >

Comment: `htmlspecialchars($string)` is not enough: use `htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_XML1 | ENT_QUOTES | ENT_DISALLOWED, 'UTF-8')` instead.